# Your thoughts on double scroll and double column form when needed

Tags: usability, forms, accessibility, scrolling

[image]

Hello, I have a problem with this wireframe display.

On this screen, the admin must answer a request (the form in the left) on the app. His response is also a form (the form in the right), where the administrator fills in the information about the request.

*I can't touch that workflow because there are statutory requirements.*

I wanted to display the information of the first form by completing the second form, with the possibility for the administrator to edit it too.
**The issue is that both forms are longer than the height of the viewport. This leaves me with two different frames with their own scrollbar so that the user can scroll into the second form without having to scroll into the first.**

Is it necessary at all costs to avoid having two scrolling bars and a two columns form?

Do you know of any inspiring work that I can seek out or a thought on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend :

- Make sections that can get collapsed
- Only have a reading interface on the right and if the admin needs to change the information to a CTA, do so (only if a change is rare).
- Avoid double scrolling altogether and calculate the height according to your wider content. Only 1 scroll.